# Como remover sombra interior do button ou input

Tags: css, html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Ao clicar no botão aparece uma sombra cinza na parte superior, criando um efeito meio que 3d, porém eu quero remove-lo.
Como eu quero que fique ao clicar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8">
            <div class="buscador">
              <form role="search">
                   <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Meu CSS até o momento:

```
.buscador button{
  background: #ffffff;
  border-left: none;
  border-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.buscador button:hover,
.buscador button:focus{
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border-color: #ccc !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Se vocês observarem bem vão reparar que o input tbm tem essa sombra interior no topo mais fraca e somente como placeholder e no button não tem  a não ser quando clica. Também quero remover essa borda da esquerda ao clicar. Como faço?

Comment: Precisa colocar na pergunta o HTML disso.

Comment: HTML Adicionado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A propriedade css que coloca sombras nos objetos é [box-shadow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp). Para retirar a sombra basta colocar

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Comment: Mano do céu eu tinha colocado isso aí mas tirei só que como estou criando no localhost tinha esquecido de limpar o cache aí não mudava nada. Obrigado problema resolvido!